# What do we know about $\sin^{2} n$?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

We all know that $-1 < \sin(n) < 1$.
What about $\sin^2(n)$? What can we say about it?
The main question is find the limit of $$\lim_{n\to\infty }\frac{\sin^2 n}{2^n}.$$

Answer (score 7):

$$0 \le \frac{\sin^2 n}{2^n} \le \frac 1{2^n} \to 0$$

Use the squeeze theorem to conclude

Note that $|x| \le 1 \implies x^2 \le 1$, so given that $-1\le \sin x \le 1$ you can conclude that $\sin^2 \le 1$ (also it is positive, but that because it is a square)
In general you have $|\sin^k x| \le 1$

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{n\to\infty }\left|\frac{\frac{\sin^2(n+1)}{2^n}}{\frac{\sin^2 n}{2^n}}\right|=\lim_{n\to\infty }\frac{\sin^2(n+1)\cdot  2^n}{\sin^2(n)\cdot 2^{n+1}}\underset{\sin (n+1)\sim \sin (n)}{=}\lim_{n\to\infty }\frac{\sin^2(n)}{\sin^2(n) \cdot 2}=\lim_{n\to\infty }\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{2}<1$$
therefore, by the ratio test, $\frac{\sin ^2 n}{2^n}\to 0$.